# charge threshold arch linux battery non thinkpad

Tags: arch-linux, battery

I use non thinkpad laptop, especially razer studio.
I want threshold charge setting to 90. But not work with tlp or bat (https://github.com/tshakalekholoane/bat).

if use BAT error permission write to /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_control_end_threshold

Any arch user work with this library?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

> I use non thinkpad laptop, especially razer studio. I want threshold
> charge setting to 90

The Threshold setting is a function of BIOS and the manufacturer's app supplied with your computer.

The ThinkPad app does not port to a non-ThinkPad laptop.

If the laptop you have does not have threshold software and the BIOS (or UEFI) setup to use threshold, then you cannot add threshold retroactively.

Check your laptop manufacturer's specifications and perhaps contact their support people.